# Regex match semicolon in vs code

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, search

I'm trying to match certain criteria, where each sentence which starts with lenevo and endswith semicolon should match.

```
lenevo hello
demo one
example;
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code with the following regex pattern.

lenevo.*?;

However, it's working into the notepad++ but not in vs code.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Use `lenevo[\w\W]*?;`

Comment: It's not in working vs code, I am using vs code version 1.67.2

Comment: It works, I also have 1.67.2. You must click on the `.*` option to enable regex search.There are a lot of options listed in the linked post: `lenevo[\S\s\r]*?;` will work, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working. i forgot to click on the .* .